# cmd redirection: equivalent of bash exec >file

Tags: cmd, io-redirection

In `bash`, with

```
exec >file
```

all output from stdout will be redirected.

Is there an equivalence in windows `cmd.exe`?

== **P.S.** ==

Why need it?

In our application, which needed to support embedded shell(cmd.exe on windows), to achieve better text search support, we decided to decouple command execution from output display.

Under bash, we have used `exec >file` to achieve that, which works seamlessly. But my cmd expertise is insufficient to find an equivalent command under windows.

== **EDIT** ==

to clarify what `exec >file` do in bash

after `exec >file` in bash, file descriptor 1, i.e., its stdout being redirected to `file`. which is different from `mycommand >file`.

In former case, stdout of shell itself being redirected, stdout of any command running inside it has not being technically redirected, but since it's child process of shell, the stdout is inherited, thus run `ls` after `exec >file`, `ls`'s output will write to `file.

In latter case, stdout of shell itself has unchanged, only child process's stdout being redirected (by shell, its parent process).

In summary, what I ask is how to redirect `cmd.exe` itself's stdout, then use `cmd.exe` interactively just as normal, except `cmd.exe` don't write anything to console, all output write to file.

Thus, below approaches **is not** what i pursuit

- `dir >file`
- `wrap_several_command_to_batch_file >file`
- `wrap_several_command_to_batch_file_and_redirect_inside_then_exit`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no equivalent to the `exec` command.

But it can be emulated by restarting the own batch file.
This works only for all commands in the batch file itself, but ends when the batch ends.

```
@echo off
REM *** Trampoline jump for function calls of the form ex. "C:\:function:\..\ownBatchFile.bat"
FOR /F "tokens=3 delims=:" %%L in ("%~0") DO goto :%%L

REM *** Emulated exec
REM *** Restart this batch file with the function name inside %0
REM *** Parameters are appended, but works only for simple parameters

call "%~d0\:exec:\..\%~pnx0" %* > file
exit /b

:exec
echo This will be redirected
```

#### If you want to redirect also from the command line, there are two different possibilities.

1. Start cmd with a redirection.

`cmd /k > file`

2. Disturb the file handles, by redirection restore failures.
   The redirection works, but can't be restored later (only by exit the cmd instance).
   Read more at [More fun with redirection and file handles](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6272)

`echo dummy >NUL 2> nul 3> file`

The second example works, because when there are multiple redirections at a time, then the restoring of the file handles fails, because the order of restoring is done in the wrong order by cmd.exe.

Comment: exec >file
'exec' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file. (version info: Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18362.657]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.)

Comment: @qeatzy I apologize, I was complete wrong, I didn't recognized the `exec` command. But my next try should work

Comment: First, Thx for your help.  One question, how to use it? I tried copy all to `.\xx.bat`, then `xx.bat` in `cmd.exe`, but nothing changed.  Second, please also see edits, and let's ensure we are in the same direction.

Comment: 1 I copy code in your answer (from @echo off to the end) into a batch file. and execute that batch file in cmd.exe, and expect `cmd.exe`'s stdout being redirected to `file`. 2 with my limited `cmd.exe` expertise, I don't find it achieve equivalent of `exec >file` in bash. 3 Have you read my lastest edit, which explain what i need by explain what `exec >file` do in bash, for clarity purpose.

Comment: Also, can you elaborate a little on `echo dummy >NUL 2> nul 3> file` a little, or provide some link that explain how it works? So that i can redirect stdin or stderr later if needed.